# How to perform subtraction in a text field of the same column and show the result as a database increment?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is above. How can I calculate the growth of the database between running the script times if I have text fields as a total_size?

[image]

[image]

I've made a query but it doesn't show the data:

```
SELECT
    b.snap_id, b.dttm - a.dttm, 
    (SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty.total_size,'','MB'), '')::numeric as t_db_growth 
     FROM snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty)
FROM 
    snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty a, 
    snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty b
WHERE 
    a.snap_id = $1 
    AND b.snap_id = $2 
ORDER BY 
    snap_id DESC;
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lag() function for this. There's a couple of ways you could get parse out the numeric size value from the string.

```
select snap_id
    , dttm
    , total_size
    , replace(total_size, ' MB', '')::numeric - lag(replace(total_size, ' MB', '')::numeric, 1) over (partition by snap_id order by dttm) as db_growth
from snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty
```

One issue with your code above is that you have your arguments switched around in your regexp_replace() statement. `regexp_replace(snapshots.snap_pg_size_pretty.total_size,'','MB')` would actually replace spaces with 'MB', not the other way around